# Cannot install melodic on PYNQ Linux, based on Ubuntu 18.04 [arm]

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am following the steps from  [the guide](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/UbuntuARM). However, when I run `apt update` I  the following:

```
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
Ign:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow InRelease
Err:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I followed [this topic](https://answers.ros.org/question/345764/e-unable-to-locate-package-ros-melodic-desktop-full-or-ros-melodic-desktop/) but that didn't solve the issue.
I also added [trusted=yes] so my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` looks like this:

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow main
```

However, I still have the same issue after running `sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
Ign:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow InRelease   
Ign:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow Release     
Ign:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main all Packages
Ign:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main armhf Packages
Ign:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main Translation-en_US
Ign:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main all Packages
Ign:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main armhf Packages
Ign:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main Translation-en_US
Ign:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main all Packages
Ign:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main armhf Packages
Ign:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main Translation-en_US
Ign:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main all Packages
Ign:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main armhf Packages
Ign:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main Translation-en_US
Ign:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main all Packages
Ign:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main armhf Packages
Ign:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main Translation-en_US
Ign:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main all Packages
Ign:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main armhf Packages
Ign:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main Translation-en_US
Ign:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main all Packages
Err:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Ign:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu glasgow/main Translation-en_US
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/glasgow/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Output of `lsb_release -a` is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: pynqlinux
Description:    PYNQ Linux, based on Ubuntu 18.04
Release:        v2.5
Codename:       glasgow
```

Could the issue be related to the codename or that there is no support or available repos for it?

Thank you for any help.

EDIT: The issue seems to be with the codename for the custom linux distribution. Therefore, editing /etc/lsb_release to include as codename `bionic` seemed to work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362311/cannot-install-melodic-on-pynq-linux,-based-on-ubuntu-18.04-%5Barm%5D/) by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2020-09-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-25**:
I've also updated the title of your question, so as to better reflect your situation.

You're not just running Ubuntu 18.04, but a derived distribution, based on it.

That changes things.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-25**:\

> EDIT: The issue seems to be with the codename for the custom linux distribution. Therefore, editing /etc/lsb_release to include as codename `bionic` seemed to work.

it's up to you, but I would not edit system files like that. `lsb_release` is managed by `apt`, so next time there is an update, your edit will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> Codename:       glasgow
> ```

This is the problem.

`glasgow` is not an Ubuntu codename for `18.04`. It's likely the name PYNQ Linux uses for its distribution.

If you are certain Ubuntu `18.04` packages are compatible with this derived distribution, then you'll need to replace that by `bionic`, everywhere it occurs in your `/etc/apt.d/ros1-latest.list`.

That would make `apt` download indices for `bionic` instead, which is a recognised codename for `18.04`.

Then, for any future invocations of `rosdep`, you'll need to add `--os=ubuntu:bionic`. And you'll want to set the [ROS_OS_OVERRIDE](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_OS_OVERRIDE) environment variable to `ubuntu:18.04:bionic` as well (note: you'll have to do this in *all* (future) shell sessions, so you may want to add it to your `.bashrc`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2020-09-25**:
Yes, I directly changed the /etc/lsb_release to have bionic but your way is safer I believe.